# What is the order in which DDP cursor changes are observed in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, ddp

Is there any guarantee that the order in which the server applies changes to the MongoDB collection are replicated at the server? I.e. will the change events (either intra-query in the case of a find-and-modify or globally between queries) be sent as a best-effort out of order but eventually consistent manner? Or will they be queued and sent in time order?